# Having issues with my Big Oh

Tags: math, big-o, discrete-mathematics

Hello was trying to work out my Big Oh but i'm not sure whats right or not.
My function is:

```
F(n)=((n+1)logn+log(n+3)-(n+1)+2)/n
```

I work out:

```
(log(n^(n+1))+log(n+3)-n+1)/n

(log((n^n)*n)+log(n+3)-n+1)/n

(log(n^n)+logn+log(n+3)-n+1)/n

(nlogn+logn+log(n+3)-n+1)/n

logn +(logn)/n+(log(n+3))/n-1+1/n
```

I can figure out that log(n+3) -> logn. But the part that im not sure is what is the Big-Oh of (logn)/n. Is it equal to nlogn or logn.

My current awnser is:

```
F(n)= logn +(logn)/n+(log(n+3))/n-1+1/n

logn +(logn)/n+(log(n+3))/n-1+1/n <= (1+1+1+1+1) nlogn     where c=5 & n0=2
```

Thanks

Comment: `log n < log (n+3) < 2*log n` for `n > 2`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand that but my question was more if (logn)/n -> nlogn

Comment: Sorry, I misread "I can't figure out...", but you wrote "I _can_ figure out...". The big-Oh of `log n / n` is `O(log n / n)`. The overall big-Oh is `O(log n)`, since the `(n+1)log n` term dominates the numerator/dividend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every `c > 0`, you can find an `n0` such that

```
\forall n > n0, log( n ) / n < c*log( n )
```

so

```
log(n)/n \in o( log(n) ) (little-oh).
```

In fact,

```
log(n)/n \in o( 1 )
```

Therefore,

```
log(n) + log(n)/n + log(n+3)/n - 1 + 1/n \in  \Theta( log(n) )
```